# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object: da ese error como si no tuviese ningún valor

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo este problema al intentar resolver un sudoku y no sé cómo arreglarlo. He intentado de todo pero no consigo ver por qué falla.

> ---> 88       pos_row, pos_col = self.get_empty(state)
>
> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Supuestamente la función devuelve las coordenadas donde el valor es igual a 0 para colocar un número que encaje y poder resolver el sudoku, pero me da ese error como si no tuviese ningún valor.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class problemSudoku (): 
    #attributes of the class are empty
    name = ""
    initial_state = {}
    goal_state = {}
    actions = []
    
    
    def __init__(self): ## init method is the constructor. 

        drive.mount('/content/drive')
        df_S = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/IA/sudoku-3.txt", header=None)
        self.name = "Sudoku"
        self.initial_state = df_S
        self.actions = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        self.rows = 9
        self.col= 9

    def get_empty(self, state):
      for row in range(self.rows):
        for col in range(self.col):
          if state.iloc[row, col] == 0:
            pos_row = row
            pos_col = col
            return (pos_row, pos_col)


    def is_applicable (self, state, action):

      in_row = False
      in_col = False
      for row in range(self.rows):
        if action in state.iloc[row, :]:
          in_row = True
          return not in_row

      for col in range(self.col):
        if action in state.iloc[:, col]:
          in_col = True
          return not in_col

      pos_row, pos_col = self.get_empty(state)

      pos_sub_block = 3*(pos_row // 3) + pos_col // 3

      sub_blocks = self.generate_sub_blocks( state)

      block = sub_blocks[pos_sub_block]

      return action not in list(block)
```

Comment: Esa función (`self.get_empty`) realmente debe devolver dos valores que se desempaquetan en las dos variables `pos_row` y `pos_col`, pero resulta que cuando la línea `if state.iloc[row, col] == 0:` no da True, se devuelve el valor `None`. Entonces, cuando se intenta desempaquetar el valor `None` en las dos variables `pos_row` y `pos_col` no se puede, porque es un solo valor.

Comment: He hecho esto, pero me da lo mismo, qué podría hacer?:  `def get_empty(self, state):
      for row in range(self.rows):
        for col in range(self.col):
          number = state[row][col]
          if number == 0:
            pos_row = row
            pos_col = col
            return (pos_row, pos_col) `

Comment: A falta de contexto no te puedo dar una respuesta exacta, porque no sé como estas llamado a los métodos de la clase `problemSudoku` ni tampoco sé como están los datos en el archivo `sudoku-3.txt`. 
Por el momento, lo que puedes hacer es modificar la línea `pos_row, pos_col = self.get_empty(state)` a esto `result = self.get_empty(state)` y después añades en la siguiente línea una comprobación `if`. Algo así : Si `if bool(result)==False` devuelves return False. De esa manera le libras del `cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`